# Html.TextBoxFor - how to turn off history

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I implemented a jQuery calendar picker so if an user clicks on Textbox, the calendar will open. However there is also an input history which covers a piece of the calendar. Is there any way of turning off the history?

**CODE**

```
    <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-1 control-label">Datum od</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.DateFrom, new {id = "date", @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.DateFrom)
    </div>
</div>

<script>$('#date').datepicker({})</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution just after I wrote the question, so I thought It would be a shame not to share. It can be easily turned off just by adding `autocomplete="off"` parameter.

So the full row is:

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.DateFrom, new { autocomplete = "off", @class = "form-control date" })
```